# How to make the program wait until tkinter GUI updates?

Tags: tkinter, screenshot

```
def text_create():

    xscr = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(0)
    yscr = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(1)

    for label in new_root.winfo_children():
        label.destroy()
    
    new_root.update_idletasks()


    img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, xscr, yscr))
    img.save('test_image.png')
    data = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, output_type='dict')
    boxes = len(data['level'])


    for i in range(boxes):
        if data['text'][i] != '':
            font = int(data['height'][i] * (2 / 3))
            create_labels(new_root, data['text'][i], font, data['left'][i], data['top'][i])  # 2/3

    new_root.after(1000,lambda:text_create())


text_create()
new_root.mainloop()
```

#create labels just creates labels. the new_root is the Tk() object. it is always at the topmost of the screen.

the problem is, before taking screenshot, i want to clear the screen of tkinter labels.
but the label destroy doesnt finish destroying the labels, the cleaned gui doesnt update before image grab grabs the screen. update_idletask doesnt update the gui as i tought it would either. in its stead i used new_root.update() and my program is running but doesnt continue past that line.

How would i make the program wait to take a screenshot until tkinter GUI updates?

Comment: Try using `new_root.update()` instead of `new_root.update_idletasks()`.

Comment: i did now. my program stalls at that line.

Comment: Calling `new_root.update()` should not freeze the application.

Comment: right. thank you. i had a piece of code that messed with framerates. it made update freeze. fixed it now.